# How can I use getElementsbyClassName?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use getElementsByClassName? I have many cards that has like this

```
         <div class="user-card Info-btn" id="Info-btn" style="display: flex; width: 400px;">
            <div class="left-card">
              <img src="" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='{{ asset('img/not-found.jpg') }}';" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="right-card">
              <div class="right-top">
                <div style="padding-top: 15px;">
                  <h1 class="user-name"></h1>
                  <h1 style="color: #B4B4B4; font-size: 10px;"></h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="right-bottom">
                <h1>Admin</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And what I want to is when you click a card a modal will display

My JS looks like this

```
var infomodal = document.getElementById("info-modal");
      
      // Get the button that opens the modal
      var infobtn = document.getElementsByClassName("Info-btn")[0];
      
      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var infospan = document.getElementsByClassName("infoclose")[0];
      

      // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
      infobtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        infomodal.style.display = "block";
      })
      
      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      infospan.addEventListener("click", function(){
        infomodal.style.display = "none";
      })
      
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.target == infomodal) {
          infomodal.style.display = "none";
        }
      })
```

It works but only the first card is able to display its modal and not the other cards.

Comment: You always points to first element, because you use `[0]`. Take a look into the Internet or here how you can iterate through an array.

Comment: Or go read up on _event delegation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` (an array-like structure). Since you extract the first element of it (via `[0]`) and add an event listener only to the first element, it is obvious that only the first card is able to display it's modal.

What you want instead is to add an event listener to *each* `infospan` element:

```js
      var infomodal = document.getElementById("info-modal");
      
      // Get the button that opens the modal
      var infobtn = document.getElementsByClassName("Info-btn"); // <-- removed [0]
      
      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var infospan = document.getElementsByClassName("infoclose"); // <-- same here
      

      // When the user clicks a button, open the modal 
      /*infobtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        infomodal.style.display = "block";
      })*/
      Array.from(infobtn).forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          infomodal.style.display = 'block';
        });
      });
      
      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      /*infospan.addEventListener("click", function(){
        infomodal.style.display = "none";
      })*/
      Array.from(infospan).forEach(span => {
        span.addEventListener('click', () => {
          infomodal.style.display = 'none';
        });
      });
      
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.target == infomodal) {
          infomodal.style.display = "none";
        }
      })
```

**EDIT**

If you know that the number and ordering of the `infospan` elements equals the number and ordering of the `infobtn` elements, you can remove one of the `.forEach` iterations:

```js
      var infomodal = document.getElementById("info-modal");
      
      // Get the button that opens the modal
      var infobtn = document.getElementsByClassName("Info-btn"); // <-- removed [0]
      
      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var infospan = document.getElementsByClassName("infoclose"); // <-- same here
      

      // When the user clicks a button, open the modal 
      /*infobtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        infomodal.style.display = "block";
      })*/
      Array.from(infobtn).forEach((btn, index) => {
        var span = infospan[index]; // <-- get the corresponding span

        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          infomodal.style.display = 'block';
        });
        span.addEventListener('click', () => {
          infomodal.style.display = 'none';
        });
      });
      
      
      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        if (event.target == infomodal) {
          infomodal.style.display = "none";
        }
      })
```

Comment: There is no need to create an array from an HTML collection object. You can use `forEach` on that by default or just use `querySelectorAll` and use the Node List. However, the smartest solution would be the usage of an Event Delegation and `closest()`

Comment: @tacoshy Are you sure? According to MDN, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` which is different from a `NodeList` and does _not_ implement `.forEach` (while the latter does). See [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) vs. [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Also the OP asked specifically how `getElementsByClassName` is used, not `querySelectorAll`. Finally, if you think using event delegation would've been a better solution, why not post it as an answer?